# How to create new button/functionality in Gmail via extension?

Tags: mysql, google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-imap

How do you add a button/whatever in a compose message window in GMail so that on the click, it brings you to a popup form that queries data from a external MySQL DB, user selects criteria, hits send, and PHP on our side slices/dices the data and inserts it into our DB.

As a bit of a visual aid, I'd like to build a extension like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jm2WEa33RCg#t=10 where there's a button, you click it, it's getting the information from somewhere, but I have no idea how or where it's doing that.

Alternatively, is there a way one can create dropdown boxes or a insert a form when  the user composes a message and get that data out?

The key functionality is the user needs to be able to access this drop down box of criteria which gets queried from the database from within Gmail. Otherwise, it's pointless.

I've been trying to figure out how to get the first part to work, and it seems like the only real method would be to develop extensions for all the major browsers.

Comment: i don't see why you don't have a form on your site to do this, i don't see the GMAIL aspect.

Comment: I do get that. It's a case of they want it all to be in Gmail and not have to go to two separate places.

Comment: There are apps that do inject buttons into Gmail (any.do comes to mind), so it's most likely possible. However, this question is just way too broad to be able help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant unless you write extensions and maintain them forever after.
There is only an api for gmail contextual gadgets but those go in the received emails not on compose.

Comment: Can you always show the contextual gadget? It seems like you always need a extractor/something in the email for it to latch onto.

Comment: Yes but you write that filter so you can always say yes